# OpenVZ and VMWare Server 1.x on the same Server

Tags: linux, vmware-server, virtualization, openvz

Has any used a server to run both OpenVZ and VMWare Server?  Are there any issues with doing this I should be aware of?

Comment: At least tell me it's a lab environment ;-)

Comment: @Matt Simmons: Well they are NORAD machines for missile launch.  But since some of the machines are old Windows 3.1 machines, I thought it would be easier to visualize them.  They all have low memory requirements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run OpenVZ and VMware Server 1.x (and 2.x) on the same system in a lab environment, and there were no apparent problems.  The base system was CentOS 5.x.  The OpenVZ instances were used for web and samba file sharing.  The VMware server was used for Windows test servers, as well as alternative distro testing.  The networking was "interesting" on OpenVZ, but that was more due to the fact that this system was tagging packets, so these problems weren't related to the dual-virtualization setup.

I have actually moved on to a KVM setup for my current lab setup.  The OpenVZ/VMWare dual setup was too labor intensive to keep going.  Mostly kernel updates would be the most headaches, as you needed an OpenVZ kernel.  Headers had to be available for VMWare to recompile.  It seemed that some issues would crop up, so it would be a few days before everything was stable again.